# SQL Issue - Sum

Tags: sql, database, db2

im tying to sum a Quantity in SQL, but im getting a error.
Does anyone know what im doing wrong?
Thanks! (sorry im not good at SQL!)
It works fine until i try to Sum BXQTOH (add sum and group by breaks it )

```
SELECT STKMP.AWPART, STKMP.AWDES1, POPTVP.BF5PLT,              
POPTVP.BF5VPT, SUM(STKB.BXQTOH)                                
 FROM stkmP INNER JOIN POPTVP ON BF5PT# = AWPART                                                         
 INNER JOIN STKB ON STKB.BXPLNT = POPTVP.BF5PLT                
AND AWPART LIKE 'Z%' AND STKB.BXPART = AWPART GROUP BY BXPLNT
```

I have extra rows i need to consolidate into one row... so basically for Z00002
i need the 0 and 1 qtys summed up into one row.
Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuX3f.png

Comment: You are missing a `SELECT`.  And your `GROUP BY` columns are not consistent with the `SELECT` columns.

Comment: sorry the code block accidentally messed up and removed my select.. fixed :)

Comment: Im trying to basically get the Qty Summed by BF5PLT ( location) and then part (AWPART) :)

Comment: you can not select other columns that there are not in your group by clause, but if you want special output maybe some data and desired output will help us to help you:)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT STKMP.AWPART, STKMP.AWDES1, POPTVP.BF5PLT,              
POPTVP.BF5VPT, sum(CAST(STKB.BXQTOH AS BIGINT))                              
 FROM stkmP INNER JOIN POPTVP ON BF5PT# = AWPART                                                         
 INNER JOIN STKB ON STKB.BXPLNT = POPTVP.BF5PLT                
AND AWPART LIKE 'Z%' AND STKB.BXPART = AWPART GROUP BY BXPLNT
```

Comment: > SELECT STKMP.AWPART, STKMP.AWDES1, POPTVP.BF5PLT,            
  POPTVP.BF5VPT, sum(CAST(STKB.BXQTOH AS BIGINT))              
   FROM stkmP INNER JOIN POPTVP ON BF5PT# = AWPART             
   INNER JOIN STKB ON STKB.BXPLNT = POPTVP.BF5PLT              
  AND AWPART LIKE 'Z%' AND STKB.BXPART = AWPART GROUP BY BXPLNT
  Column AWPART or expression in SELECT list not valid.

Gives this error of AWPART or expression in select list not valid :(